# Docker-compose starting containers twice, running command twice and have same content

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I get the server container twice, and the view container has the server's content. I have no idea what is going on...

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
    server: 
        build: ./server
    view:
        build: ./view
        ports: 8080:80
```

**Server Dockerfile**

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**View Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./src /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The images build fine.

[image]

Is this normal? Looks like node is starting twice?

[image]

Both containers have the **same** content. This doesn't look right.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with a Python web server which was working fine before I added in docker-compose.  Did you find an explanation that you could pass along?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I pretty much re-installed everything and it was working normally.

Answer (score -1):

When you do `docker-compose up` it will start streaming all logs from all containers that were brought up.

This simply looks like `server_1` output some stuff, and then `view_1` output some stuff, and then `server_1` output some more stuff, etc...

If you want to see the logs for an individual service, you can run `docker-compose logs server` or `docker-compose logs view`, and get the logs for a specific service only.

Comment: I don't think what you are saying answers the question. According to the question docker-compose is running the same docker twice which shouldn't be the case.